# Is a verb preceded by a determiner still a verb?

Tags: verbos, classe-gramatical

I find it strange for **an infinitive verb** to be **preceded by a determiner**. To my ears it sounds more like a noun.  e.g. **"o meu sofrer"** (my suffering) **o meu padecer** (my endurance) etc.  My question is: are these verbs classified as "verbs in the infinitive" or could they be nouns?

Acho estranho um verbo no infinitivo ser precedido por um determinante; a mim **soa mais como um substantivo**.  Por exemplo: **"o meu sofrer"**, **"o teu penar"**, **"o meu sonhar"**, **"o meu padecer"**, etc. E minha pergunta é: nos exemplos acima, a classificação gramatica é a de um verbo no infinitivo?

Consultei alguns dicionários e não há menção alguma a substativo no caso dos verbos acima.

Comment: O infinitivo é uma das ***formas nominais*** do verbo, e por tanto pode funcionar como frase de substantivo.

Comment: No comentário acima, leia-se "sintagma nominal" onde se lê "frase de substantivo" (*noun phrase*).

Comment: @tchrist a pergunta, então, seria se — ao não funcionar como verbo—  eses «verbos» seguem sendo-o :-)  En alguns casos, é evidente que se trata duma lexicalização e por tanto sem dúvida é substantivo (por exemplo, «ser»), noutros casos, quando encabeça uma locução verbal, e plenamente evidente que segue como verbo com função substantival.  Mas se é só o infinitivo sem objetos o adverbios correspondentes, diria que pode ocupar um espaço cinza.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso pode acontecer não só com verbos, mas com muitos outros casos. Chamamos isso de *substantivação*.

Exemplo:

> **O andar** dele é lento. -> verbo no infinitivo substantivado
>
> Eu gosto **de andar**. -> verbo no infinitivo

Você pode ler um pouco mais e estudar sobre os casos nesse link:
http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/dicas/001/dica150.html

> Além disso, a palavra substantivada pode assumir qualquer função sintática reservada ao substantivo, como **sujeito** - que foi o caso dos seus exemplos na pergunta:
>
> **Exemplo:** *Seu andar*(sujeito) é lento.